# Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class RCTFileReaderModule

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class RCTFileReaderModule for the name 'FileReaderModule', but name was already registered by class FileReaderModule

This error occurs when trying to start an application on ios using the command react-native run-ios
If using Xcode app worked (android worked not problem)

[image: error]

[image: libraries in Xcode]

This problem torments me not one day
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post your Main Application java please? Also, is this a custom module?

Comment: Sorry i didn't quite understand
You mean MainApplication.java?
Android work not problem

Comment: Apologies - I misread that. Sounds like you have linked to 2 of the same libraries. Can you see open your libraries in XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JRK mentions in the comments, "you have linked to 2 of the same libraries." I had the same issue and the problem for me was that I had RCTText, RCTNetwork, RCTWebSocket, and RCTAnimation linked in my `ios/Podfile` and *also* linked as libraries on my app.

In the case of `RCTFileReaderModule`, I believe that's a dependency of `RCTNetwork`. In the screenshot that you shared, you'll see that you have RCTNetwork.xcodeproj under your libraries. If you also have a line in your Podfile that says `RCTNetwork`, then you should delete the library dependency (right-click, `Delete`, and `Remove Reference`).

Once you do this, I believe you will continue to have errors for each `RCT` library linked in your Podfile. If you do *not* have these things in your Podfile, then I would check elsewhere for duplicates.

I have not confirmed whether you can just delete the line in the Podfile instead. I'm guessing you can but I opted to stick with the Podfile dependency since it's easier to see and manage.