# Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class LRNAnimationViewManager for the name 'LottieAnimationView', but name was already registered by

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I am trying to run 'lottie' for React Native however after successful XCODE build, I get an error:

> Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class LRNAnimationViewManager for the name 'LottieAnimationView', but name was already registered by...

Similar issue:

[Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class RCTFileReaderModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661861/attempted-to-register-rctbridgemodule-class-rctfilereadermodule).

Uninstalling, unlinking and reinstalling, relinking does not seem to work. Installed the correct version of 'lottie-ios', 'lottie-react-native' associated with >RN 0.58 on:

https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/blob/master/README.md#getting-started.

Also tried adding "Lottie.framework" in the 'embedded framework' tab of XCODE. I am trying to set up the animation screens using this package.

Any leads/suggestions welcomed and thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The versions of `lottie-ios` and `lottie-react-native` matter depending on the `react-native` version you have on your package.json.

### For React Native == 0.59.x (which is used by Expo sdk 35 and 36):

Install `lottie-react-native` (3.0.2) and `lottie-ios` (3.0.3):

```
yarn add lottie-react-native@3.0.2
yarn add lottie-ios@3.0.3
```

or

```
npm i --save lottie-react-native@3.0.2
npm i --save lottie-ios@3.0.3
```

Do not use `react-native link` to add the library to your project, if you are using ExpoKit.

```
react-native link lottie-ios
react-native link lottie-react-native
```

Note:

Go to your ios folder and run:

```
pod install
```

## If you get the error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "lottie-ios":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    lottie-ios

  In Podfile:
    ExpoKit/Core (from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.13.0`) was resolved to 35.0.0, which depends on
      lottie-ios (~> 2.5.0)

    lottie-ios (from `../node_modules/lottie-ios`)
```

You would better remove the `pod lottie-ios` and `pod lottie-react-native` from your Podfile, because ExpoKit will have the dependencies sorted out when you run `pod install`.